# what is the meaning of Det in the context of multiplication of two matrices

Tags: matrices, determinant

Does such a Determinant indicate a structural relationship between two variables for which matrices have been indicated.

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Multiplicativity_and_matrix_groups)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two-by-two matrices can be realised as linear transformations/functions on the plane. The determinant of a two by two matrix is the (signed) area of the transformation of the unit square (corners $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)$).

Comment: thanks. I am just looking at it if we have standardized values in these matrices. I am not a mathematician and am a naïve applied statistician. I am interested in understanding whether Det indicates the magnitude of interrelatedness (mutual). please bear with my novice knowledge.

Comment: Ah... well the first column of your matrix describes what the matrix will do to $(1,0)$ and the second column describes where $(0,1)$ will go. If the two columns are equal for example then the two points are sent to a single point and the transformed unit square is now a line... with an area of 0.

Comment: @amWhy I don't think this is necessary.

Comment: @amwhy this answer is from over eight years ago... I doubt I have answered many similarly poor questions in the last three years.

Comment: Oh my, @JP.  I did not catch the date of the post.  Apologies!  (I edited your answer only so I could reverse my downvote.   And I will be more vigilant in attending to the date of posts.  It popped up in the "close review queue" today, for closure of the question.